# Create dropdown from #(prompt) in passthrough?

Tags: teradata, cognos

I've got a where statement that looks like this

```
WHERE       REPORTTYPE IN   (#PROMPTMANY('ENTER VALUE','STRING')#)
```

Cognos prompts me to enter a value, but what if I wanted it to show a dropdown box with predefined selections?

Comment: What part of Cognos prompts you? I assume your report is built in Report Studio? Please clarify

Comment: Take the prompt macro out of your query subject in Framework Manager, and create it in your report.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid , you are correct. I've built it in Report Studio. Its just SQL embedded into the report. When you run the report, it comes up as a prompt, but its not a prompt page.

Comment: @Andrew So this may be a stupid question, because I'm newer to cognos. If I set this up as a prompt/filter instead, does cognos modify the query appropriately. The tables that this query pulls from have 40+ millions rows a piece, therefore I was trying to trim it down from the where clause.

Comment: If you add something to the where clause in FM or Report Studio it's the same result - the SQL is adjusted to include it in the where clause. Prompt macro syntax can be tricky. You don't actually need to use a prompt macro in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to control the look and feel of prompts in Cognos Report Studio is to create a custom prompt page. If you give a custom prompt the same parameter name as an embedded prompt macro, that custom prompt will be used instead of the system prompt to satisfy that macro.

The basic steps are:

1. Create a custom prompt page
2. Add a value prompt and set its parameter to the exact name of the parameter defined in the prompt macro
3. Configure the UI property of the value prompt to display as a drop-down
4. Configure your static values in the properties of the value prompt

I've assumed here that you want to manually configure the values available in the drop-down. If you want a query to dynamically supply the values, then create a query to return the values and set the Query and Use Value and Display Value properties instead of step 4 above.

Note: Make sure your use value is the same type as the value that your SQL is expecting. The use value is always the value used in filters and marcos. The display values are only there for display purposes.

Comment: Excellent answer. Could you perhaps extend it to provide an explanation of how this can be done without a prompt macro at all (since it is redundant)

Comment: Prompt macros can't be avoided in all situations. For instance, if you need the prompt to act like an optional prompt while still keeping it set to required or if you need highly optimized SQL code such as a WHERE EXISTS construct, prompt macros are sometimes the only solution. The advice I provided applies to all prompt macros whether they are in report-level custom SQL or used in model-level query subjects.

Comment: In this particular case, a prompt macro is not necessary, and I think it's only being used because it is being built in FM.

Comment: I don't think there is enough information in the question to determine if a prompt macro is necessary or not.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and worked perfectly. Awesome man, thank you. Outside of the scope of this, any recommended resources on learning more about Cognos report development? I'm not sure I totally understand how FM fits into Cognos report development, so any recommendations would be appreciated. If not, thanks for the help on this!.

Comment: Recommendations of extended learning are beyond the scope and discouraged by this site. If you look at my profile, there's a link to my blog. If you go there, you can contact me directly and I'll try to help.

Comment: A prompt macro is not necessary to support an in clause. But you're right there isn't much info in the question